# Effective closures in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

With Python 2.7x I'm attempting to create a Map object which can reference itself with a 'This' or 'self'. In Javascript this would be roughly,

```
myObj = function(){ 
 obj = {}; 
 this = obj; 
 obj = { 'a':'b', 'b':this.a };
 return obj;
}()
```

But in Python you can't do multi-line lambda expressions. Scoping also doesn't behaviour the same as I expect. I can create a function on a separate line then call it, but this seems to lack pizzaz (especially since it isn't limited to being called only once).
Is there an effective way to do this in Python?

EDIT: Some people have been asking *OH MY GOD WHY????* Well first of all, as an exercise. Second, you are failing to understand what I'm trying to do - I'm attempting to emulate a CLASS with a MAP. In a class in python you would say, 
    var otherfunc = self.predefinedFunction
I want to be able to use self (this in some other languages), to reference the object. So in python I want to turn this:

```
my_obj = { 'sqr':lambda x: x*x, 'quad': my_obj['sqr']}
```

into this:

```
my_obj = { 'sqr':lambda x: x*x, 'quad': this['sqr']}
```

Comment: So JavaScript lets you create an unreadable mess that takes a couple of minutes to sort out what it is doing, and you want to do this in Python too, exactly, *why*?

Comment: What exactly is wrong with `b_value = 'b'` and `myObj = {'a': b_value, 'b': b_value}`?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but why does the example you show need to be in a function at all?

Comment: You cannot assign to `this` in JS.

Comment: The short answer is you can't initialize a variable and refer to it in the same line

Comment: Or, if you have to have a lambda: `myObj = (lambda b_value='b': {'a': b_value, 'b': b_value})()` but that still has too high a [WTFs/min quotient](http://www.osnews.com/story/19266/WTFs_m).

Comment: Maybe it would help us understand what you're _really_ trying to do if you post some Python code that shows how you want to use `myObj`.

Comment: Why not parse as JSON with `json` module?

Comment: Added clarification.

Comment: So you want a class, without actually creating a class? This would be extremely simple with a class. You could even add a `__getitem__` method so you could access attributes of the object as if it were a dict/map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your example in your answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28503891/529630), why don't you just write a class? The following is functionally equivalent to your code example.

```
class myobj(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.count = 0
    @staticmethod
    def addOne(n):
        return n + 1
    def addOneTimesTwo(self, n):
        return self.addOne(n) * 2
    def __getitem__(self, attrname):
        "Allows attributes to accessed as if they were key/value pairs in a map."
        return getattr(self, attrname)

myObj = myobj()
assert myObj["addOneTimesTwo"](1) == 4
```

If you really have your heart set on trying to emulate prototyping then you could try the following. It won't work with inheritance though. You'll need to add a few more bits and pieces to make that work.

```
class Prototype(object):    
    def __init__(self, **attrs):
        self.__dict__.update(attrs)

def myobj():
    count = 0
    def addOne(n):
        return n + 1
    def addOneTimesTwo(n):
        """This is like a 'bound' method. The self in this context will refer to the same
        Prototype even if this function is transferred to a different Prototype."""
        return self.addOne(n) * 2
    self = Prototype(**locals())
    return self

myObj = myobj()
assert myObj.addOneTimesTwo(1) == 4
```

Comment: Its a style thing, and its an exercise I'm doing. I'm doing it where there is exactly one object of each type. Or to model prototypical inheritance. Though this is an interesting way of doing it - if no one else answers with the exact thing (which I suspect doesn't exist) I'll probably give you the answer. :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to implement a closure with a map, this would work fine

```
mymap = {a:1,b:"foo"} # all of your previously initialized and constant data
mymap["self"] = mymap
```

Then you can call

```
mymap["self"]["b"]
```

Here's how you can write code using this

```
mymap["func"] = lambda x: return x*mymap["self"]["x"]
```

This is admitted ugly, but you can't you have no way to refer to the map as anything but a global variable within a lambda expression.  In particular, there's no good way to self reference. A better approach is to use an object, not a map.

Comment: This doesn't work, I want to use self WITHIN the map to represent the map

Comment: You can make it work, it's just not pretty, see my edits and @Dunes answer

Answer (score 0):

With the following boilerplate code:

```
class StoringOperations:
    for specfunc in ["getattr", "getitem", "call", "len"]:  # Extend as needed
        name = "__" + specfunc + "__"
        f = lambda self, *args, __name=name, **kwargs: StoredOperation(self, __name, args, kwargs)
        f.__name__ = name
        locals()[name] = f


class StoredOperation(StoringOperations):
    def __init__(self, s, methname, args, kwargs):
        self.__args = args
        self.__kwargs = kwargs
        self.__methname = methname
        self.__s = s
        super().__init__()


def gethiddenname(thing, name):
    return getattr(thing, "_StoredOperation" + name)


def consolidate(thing, this):
    if isinstance(thing, StoredOperation):
        s = consolidate(gethiddenname(thing, "__s"), this)
        methname = gethiddenname(thing, "__methname")
        try:
            meth = getattr(s, methname)
        except AttributeError:
            if methname == "__getattr__":
                meth = lambda *args, **kwargs: getattr(s, *args, **kwargs)
            else:
                raise
        return meth(*gethiddenname(thing, "__args"), **gethiddenname(thing, "__kwargs"))
    elif isinstance(thing, StoringOperations):
        return this
    else:
        return thing


class SelfConsciousMap(dict):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()
        self.kwargs = kwargs
        for key in kwargs:
            self.consolidation(key)

    def consolidation(self, key):
        self[key] = consolidate(self.kwargs[key], self)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if key in self.kwargs and key not in self:
            self.consolidation(key)
        return super().__getitem__(key)


this = StoringOperations()
```

You can do this:

```
d = SelfConsciousMap(a=[1,2,3], b=this["a"], c=this["b"].copy(), d=this["a"].__len__())
print(d)
```

And you will get:

```
{'a': [1, 2, 3], 'c': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [1, 2, 3], 'd': 3}
```

Might not be useful in *real* code, but it shows that with enough classes, anything is possible...